# How to swap elements in 2d array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, swap

I'm trying to make a 15 puzzle game by swapping an element with the position of a blank element. I've made this code, but it only swaps when the tile is to the right or below for some reason.

```
void moveTile(int gameBoard[][SIZE], int nextMove, int &blanki, int &blankj)   
{
int temp=nextMove;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        if(gameBoard[i][j]==nextMove)
        {
            gameBoard[i][j]=gameBoard[blanki][blankj];
            gameBoard[blanki][blankj]=temp;
            blanki=i;
            blankj=j;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The typical way of swapping two things with help of a temporary is  the three steps `temp = first_thing; first_thing = second_thing; second_thing = temp;`.   Your code is not doing anything like that.

Comment: Or use the [std::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) function.

Answer (score 0):

Walk thru it in a debugger.  You'll see that after a swap is made, you keep going and searching.  In the case where the tile is above or left, you'll swap a second time.

You need to stop searching once you've made a swap.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated it to include a stop, now the code does not iterate.

```
void moveTile(int gameBoard[][SIZE], int nextMove, int &blanki, int &blankj)
{   bool stop=false;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
    {
        while(!stop)
        {if(gameBoard[i][j]==nextMove)
        {
            int temp=gameBoard[i][j];
            gameBoard[i][j]=gameBoard[blanki][blankj];
            gameBoard[blanki][blankj]=temp;
            blanki=i;
            blankj=j;
            stop=true;
        }
        }
    }
}

}
```